# How can I countdown in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a timer tool that goes right with the related link https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-voice-p4lbh?file=/src/CounterTimeStyled.js. My goal is to select the left hour, minute and second information, render it on the screen and start it again. I want to countdown. Do you have this help?

Comment: The question itself is not descriptive. Can you elaborate a little, by adding an examble or so.

Comment: actually i want to create a countdown widget in the form of hours minutes and seconds

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this approach](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-countdown-timer-react-hooks) or [this one](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-in-react-app-e99916046292).